# Script to download stock price data from yahoo finance, randomly 404s

Tags: python, csv, download, http-status-code-404, yahoo-finance

the following script reads a .txt of ticker symbols of companies to download the corresponding financial informations in a .csv . The data is pulled from Yahoo Finance and saved in a local directory.

```py
import urllib.request
import requests
import time

#Define the URL to download the .csv from.
url_begin = "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="
url_end = "&a=00&b=1&c=1950&d=11&e=31&f=2050&g=d&ignore=.csv"


#Function that reads all available ticker symbols from ticker_daten.txt. This file should be in the same directory as the program.
def readTickers(file):
    read_ticker = []
    ins = open( file, "r" )
    for line in ins:
        if line.endswith('\n'):
            line=line[:-1]
        read_ticker.append(line)
    ins.close()
    return read_ticker

#File location for tickersymbols to download
tickers = readTickers("C:/Users/Win7ADM/Desktop/Jonas/stock-price-leecher/ticker_daten.txt")

#Loop through list of ticker symbols and download .csv's .
for i in tickers:

    #Forge downloadable link.
    link_created = url_begin + i + url_end

    #Make sure that the link actually leads to a file.
    try:
        r = requests.head(link_created)
        if r.status_code==404:
            print(str(r.status_code)+": No page found!")
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            print(link_created)

            #Finally download the file, if it does exist.
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(link_created, "C:/Users/Win7ADM/Desktop/Jonas/stock-price-leecher/data/"+i+".csv")
            time.sleep(0.5)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        #A Connection error occurred.
        print ("ConnectionError: 404 No page found!")
    except requests.HTTPError:
        #An HTTP error occurred.
        print ("HTTPError!")
    except requests.Timeout:
        #Connection timed out.
        print ("Timeout!")
```

**The Problem:** The script crashes randomlyafter loading between 20-1750 .csv's. The crash produces the following output.

```
Process started >>>
http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=0055.HK&a=00&b=1&c=1950&d=11&e=31&f=2050&g=d&ignore=.csv
http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=0056.HK&a=00&b=1&c=1950&d=11&e=31&f=2050&g=d&ignore=.csv
http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=0057.HK&a=00&b=1&c=1950&d=11&e=31&f=2050&g=d&ignore=.csv
http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=0058.HK&a=00&b=1&c=1950&d=11&e=31&f=2050&g=d&ignore=.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Stock-Price Leecher.py", line 40, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(link_created, "C:/Users/Win7ADM/Desktop/Jonas/stock-price-leecher/data/"+i+".csv")
  File "c:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 178, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "c:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 461, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 571, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 499, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 579, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

Does anyone of you have any Idea why this might happen?

Comment: Maybe the service you're using is rate limiting in such an odd way?

Comment: hi joozek, thanks for your reply. I also thought of that and even though I dont have a definite source I believe to have read that yahoo finance allows more than 2000 querries per hour.
The other thing that exceeds my understanding is that the output states a 404 error. My script is capable of catching those.